# What is the best technique to format Rails models for logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, model, formatting

So we need to log something that happened in a Rails application:

```
logger.info("Created zone #{zone} for user #{user}.")
```

`zone` and `user` are standard models, that is, objects of `ActiveRecord::Base`-derived classes. And the default output is not very useful:

```
Created zone #<Zone:0x007f93b3709498> for user #<User:0x007f93b3509418>.
```

For debugging purposes, it makes sense to output at least model `id`s. It would also be nice to see some key attributes (the set of which varies from model to model), like `user.name` and `zone.area`.

`inspect` would be an overkill because some of our models (`User` included) have many non-key attributes that are not immediately useful and would only clutter logs.

Overriding `to_s` doesn't feel right because models should be concerned with their state, not presentation. Also, this "short inspect" is something that's only needed in logs, not *every* time we want to output models.

What is the best way to format Rails models for logs?

Comment: Where should I ask questions like these?

Answer (score 2):

My immediate thoughts are:

1. Why are you logging these?
2. What are your requirements for this log, if it's this important?

These will steer you in the direction you need to go.  If you want to use string interpolation like that, `to_s` is what will be called.

To keep the information out of the models you could use [concerns](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) to mix it in:

```
# app/models/concerns/user/log_format.rb
module Concerns::User::LogFormat
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  def to_log_format
    "Hey I'm a User and I have some #{attributes}!"
  end
end
```

Mix it in to `User`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Concerns::User::LogFormat
end
```

Then you could open up `Logger` and add a smart'ish method:

```
class ActiveSupport::Logger
  def log_models(level, message, *args)
    args = args.map { |arg| arg.try(:to_log_format) || arg }
    self.send(level, sprintf(message, *args))
  end
end
```

Then you can call it:

```
user = ...
zone = ...
logger.log_models(:info, "Created zone %s for user %s.", zone, user)
```

Seems like a long way to go to log a bunch of information, for what purpose?  If you have a specific purpose, perhaps the general application log is not the place for this to go.

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgot about good old string formatting!